# What does "passion-tearing" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, literature, theater

What does "passion-tearing" mean in the following context?

> My parents were at the summer theater singing a first matinee performance of "You Can't Take It With You". In summer stock productions they were two very irritable, **passion-tearing**, perspiring players, and my younger brothers and I rarely went to see them. My mother was especially poor in summer stock. Watching her, even on a cool evening, Kenneth used to cringe in his seat till he was almost on the floor.

It doesn't sound like a good thing, but I cannot figure out what it actually means.

The story is written somewhere around 1947 and full context is available [here](http://inkacademy.blogspot.no/2013/12/j-d-salinger-ocean-full-of-bowling-balls_18.html).

Comment: It's a particularly strong form of voluntearing.

Comment: I must admit I've never heard it before.  I think it *might* mean "tearing up in passion" which from the sense of the rest of the context could mean "overacting".  As you no doubt noticed, a Google search for the phrase comes up pretty dry, so I wonder if this is a neologism.

Comment: Or it might be a particularly passionate episode of ripping something up. There are two verbs spelled _tear_, and by far the more common is pronounced /ter/, not /tir/.

Comment: @JohnLawler "voluntearing" sounds very reasonable, but the story wa written around 1945-1947 and "voluntearing" sounds fairly new (1983) compared to that. I'll also add that detail to the question.

Comment: It looks to me like a [nonce word](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonce_word) (or phrase).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the following passages in [Emotional Excess on the Shakespearean Stage: Passion's Slaves](http://goo.gl/0NFZFB)

[image]

[image]

More here (without explanation) from [The Knickerbocker: Or, New-York Monthly Magazine, Volume 11](http://goo.gl/CDN9IL)

[image]

Comment: I wonder if there is synonym to it. Since "passion-tearing" doesn't seem so popular, there should be some other word/phrase that means more or less the same...

Comment: I wondered the same. Never heard of this before...

Answer (score 1):

Passion-tearing = Dramatic over-acting.
Woe-is-me loud wailing declamations and dramatic expressions of grief / joy / ... .

Google Ngram results help heaps. 
Click blue year-ranges at bottom of page for source examples

[NGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=passion+tearing&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpassion%20tearing%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cpassion%20tearing%3B%2Cc0)

Occurrences:

[image]

The Musical times, 1920 usage [here](https://books.google.co.nz/books?id=ITs0AQAAMAAJ&q=%22passion+tearing%22&dq=%22passion+tearing%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjBuqfhppXlAhWK7HMBHcinBTYQ6AEIejAO)

[image]

Hamlets instructions to actors analysed [here](https://books.google.co.nz/books?id=aRsTAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA139&dq=%22passion+tearing%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiCiKaJppXlAhW8_XMBHfPzBB8Q6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=%22passion%20tearing%22&f=false)